# Ajax jQuery retrieving data from previous query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm currently using Ajax & jQuery for my chat, some might say its stupidly complex but so long as I can get it working.

It works on the first friend result, how ever not on the other. What its doing is the chat-load.php (Ajax part) is creating a new query to select the friends details, which are then being put into a result query on the chat.php page.

Therefore it only displays one "Working" chat window for the 1st friend. I tried grabbing the previous friend_id from the chat.php query and using it in the chat-load.php query but it didn't seem to notice any data.

Here is an example of what I'm getting, 1st result full width meaning its working, other results not full width as not working with ajax.

[image]

This is my current setup:

**chat.php**

```html
<?php $users = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, 
    message.date, message.time, message.message, message.recipient, message.sender
FROM users 
JOIN friends
    ON users.id IN (friends.sender, friends.recipient)
JOIN message 
    ON (users.id = message.sender)
AND 75 IN (message.sender,message.recipient)
ORDER BY message.date DESC, message.time DESC");   ?>




                <!-- Friends query -->


<?php $users = $db->query("SELECT IF(friends.sender = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"].", friends.recipient, friends.sender) AS user_id
FROM friends
WHERE friends.sender = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"]."
    OR friends.recipient = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"]."");   ?>


 <?php while($friend = $users->fetch_object()): ?>

<?php  $friends = $db->query("SELECT firstname, lastname, id FROM users WHERE id = $friend->user_id "); ?>
 <?php while($FriendName = $friends->fetch_object()): ?>



        <div class="chat-box">
            <div class="header">
<?= $FriendName->firstname ?> <?= $FriendName->lastname ?>  <?= $FriendName->id ?>        

            </div>

                <script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#chat-box, #messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
});
</script>
   <script>
function loadlink(){
    $('#messages').load('chat-load.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 100);
</script>


            <div id="messages" class="messages">



            </div>

            <div class="input-box">
                    <form id="SendForm" class="SendMsg" role="form" method="post">
   <input type="text" id="s_firstname" name="s_firstname" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SESSION["user"]["firstname"] ?>" />
   <input type="text" id="s_lastname" name="s_lastname" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SESSION["user"]["lastname"] ?>" />
   <input type="text" id="sender" name="sender" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SESSION["user"]["id"] ?>" />
   <input type="text" id="r_firstname" name="r_firstname" class="MsgInputHidden"value="<?= $FriendName->firstname ?>" />
   <input type="text" id="r_lastname" name="r_lastname" class="MsgInputHidden"value="<?= $FriendName->lastname ?>" />
   <input type="text" id="recipient" name="recipient" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $FriendName->id ?>" />
      <input type="text" id="ip" name="ip" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] ?>" />
      <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= date('Y-m-d') ."\n" ?>" />
      <?php
$now = time(); 
$utc_time = $now - intval(date('Z', $now)); 

?>

      <input type="text" id="time" name="time" class="MsgInputHidden" value="<?= '' . date('H:i:s', $now) . '' ?>" />

                    <input id="message" type="text" name="message" style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
                       <input id="submit" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

                    </form>






            </div>
        </div>
            <script>
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var message = $("#message").val();
var s_firstname = $("#s_firstname").val();
var s_lastname = $("#s_lastname").val();
var sender = $("#sender").val();
var r_firstname = $("#r_firstname").val();
var r_lastname = $("#r_lastname").val();
var recipient = $("#recipient").val();
var ip = $("#ip").val();
var date = $("#date").val();
var time = $("#time").val();
var dataString = '&message=' + message + '&s_firstname=' + s_firstname + '&s_lastname=' + s_lastname + '&sender=' + sender + '&r_firstname=' + r_firstname + '&r_lastname=' + r_lastname + '&recipient=' + recipient + '&ip=' + ip + '&date=' + date + '&time=' + time;  
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url:'sendmessagefriend.php',

  });
});

</script>
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
$("#SendForm").get(0).reset();
});
</script>
<script>
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  $("#chat-box, #messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
});
</script>
         <?php endwhile; ?> 

                 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**chat-load.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <?php
    session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user"]) or !is_array($_SESSION["user"]) or empty($_SESSION["user"])
)

      // redirect to index page if not superuser
header('Location: index.php');
?>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','****','****','****');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");

$sql="SELECT message, sender, recipient, date, time, IF(recipient = ".$_SESSION["user"]["id"].", 'received', 'sent') AS direction FROM message WHERE recipient IN (".$_SESSION["user"]["id"].", ".$friend->user_id.") AND sender IN (".$_SESSION["user"]["id"].", ".$friend->user_id.")";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<ul>";
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<span class='". $row['direction'] ."'>". $row['message'] ."</span>";
    echo "<div class='clear'></div>";
    echo "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";


}
mysqli_close($con); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.ajax()` instead of `$.load()`. Set `cache: false`.

Example:

```
function loadlink(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'chat-load.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
             $('#messages').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I just tried $.ajax() and it seems like it didn't even load the chat-load.php file.
`$('#messages').ajax('chat-load.php',function () {`

Comment: function loadlink(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'chat-load.php',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
             $('#messages').html(result);
        }
    });
}

Comment: @CasperRound, print the result of the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request inside the`#messages`'s html using the `success` parameter like this: `success: function(result){ $('#messages').html(result); }` to see that is working.

Comment: Okay Ill give that ago. I'm currently re-writing it now, ill let you know if I get anywhere